# How do I declare a java HashMap in my .idl file when using Corba?

Tags: java, corba, idl

I need my idl to compile something exactly like this. Been stuck for hours trying a bunch of things.

```
module SomeApp
{
    interface Something
    {
        HashMap myMethod();
    };
};
```

I tried

```
struct KeyVal {
    string key;
    string value;
};
typedef HashMap<string,string> hash;
```

But then none of my java code will work using KeyVal[]

Answer (score 1):

With CORBA you have to define your interfaces and types according to the [IDL](https://www.omg.org/spec/CORBA/) specification. IDL doesn't have a `HashMap` type, you could use a `sequence`, see below for an example IDL that works.

```
module SomeApp
{
  struct KeyVal {
    string key;
    string value;
  };
  typedef sequence<KeyVal> KeyValSeq; 

  interface Something
  {
    KeyValSeq myMethod();
  };
};
```

Comment: Just realized I didn't respond to this. Thanks for your help.